# spacy nlp is taking long time to answer (django backend)

Tags: django, nlp, spacy

I have django backend and I'm using spacy for text processing

Here is a sample of my code

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

def process_data(jd):
    # print(jd)
    print('process_data start', time.time())
    #doc = nlp(jd)
    doc = nlp.pipe([jd])
    print('process_data pipe', time.time())
    for each in doc:
        print('process_data inside loop', time.time())
        doc = each
        print('process_data done loop', time.time())
    print('process_data nlp', time.time())
```

Here is the output of the same

```
process_data start 1603023551.9794967
process_data pipe 1603023551.979678
process_data inside loop 1603023564.9438393
process_data done loop 1603023565.172661
process_data nlp 1603023565.2528574
process_data skills 1603023570.6167505
```

spacy.load occurs when the application is initialised itself... but if you see to get inside the for loop is taking a lot of time (1603023564.9438393 - 1603023551.979678)

Could anyone suggest how to make it faster

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#processing):

> Only apply the pipeline components you need. Getting predictions from the model that you don’t actually need adds up and becomes very inefficient at scale. To prevent this, use the disable keyword argument to disable components you don’t need – either when loading a model, or during processing with nlp.pipe. See the section on disabling pipeline components for more details and examples.

This is how you disable components:

```
for doc in nlp.pipe(texts, disable=["tagger", "parser"]):
    ... whatever ...
```

---

As a separate issue, what is `jd`? If it's a single string then using `nlp.pipe` isn't going to help. If it's a very long string (like many pages), you might be better off splitting it on paragraph breaks or other natural splits and using `nlp.pipe` on that.

---

Also this is clearly going to cause problems. I suspect this is not your actual code, but if it is you should fix it.

```
for each in doc:
    doc = each
```

Comment: thanks @polm23. I need all the components, ideally doc = list(doc)[0]... this part was taking a lot of time... so I re-wrote it as a for loop...observed that going inside for loop is taking a lot of time.. which is quite strange.... how to explain such a behaviour